# codeartifact cleanup / remove multiple packages - or how to skip it for some pip install packages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, aws-codeartifact

Does anyone know a simple way to cleanup codeartifact?

I use it as relay (external connection) for python packages (pypi-store) as I don't see a way to use codeartifact only for private packages. Means if I install a private package from codeartifact, it also downloads the dependencies and they are stored then as well there and use many GBs.

The Webgui provides no way to select and delete multiple packages.

Another way to aviod this would be to force pip command to use codeartifact only for a specific package and the rest from official python repository. But I did not find a way to do this.